# Delphi: How to call one form from another?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a more complex dialog type form (called frmComment), that uses a Tmemo field and some labels.  I figured out that if I run frmComment.Show it will show the form, but processing does not stop.  Basically, how do I get processing of the procedure to stop until the form is closed?

Or if this is not advisable, what is the best approach to create a more complex dialog-like form (that stops processing of the program and returns something useful).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to call `ShowModal` instead of `Show` and the dialog will be modal.

[Modal dialogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) disable the other windows in an application so that the modal dialog, and only the modal dialog, can receive input.